# Python Threading Self Calling Threads Unexpected Behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am testing a method to run several tasks in parallel. These tasks will run in parallel threads and I want the tasks to repeat until a global variable is set. I am first trying threading to launch the parallel threads, and make sure they will work properly. What I have so far:

```
import threading
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time

i = 0
j = 0
def main():
    global i
    global j
    t1 = threading.Thread(name = "task1", target = task1)
    t2 = threading.Thread(name = "task2", target = task2)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

def task1():
    global i
    i += 1
    time.sleep(10)
    t1 = threading.Thread(name = "task1", target = task1)
    t1.start()

def task2():
    global j
    j -= 1
    time.sleep(10)
    t2 = threading.Thread(name = "task2", target = task2)
    t2.start()

tmain = threading.Thread(name = "main", target = main)
tmain.start()
```

which starts a main thread that then starts two threads which run task1 and task2. To monitor the current threads and the values of i and j I run:

```
while(True):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    for thread in threading.enumerate():
        print(thread)
    print(i)
    print(j)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

(all of this is being run in a Jupyter Notebook).

Running the script above, i noticed some unexpected results. I expect that at any given time, there should be at most two threads of task1 and task2, but instead I observe many more threads of task2 compared to task1. These are not ghost or finished threads, because the absolute values of i and j grow disproportionately. Two observations I made:
[image: observation 1, 1 task1 thread and 5 task2 threads]
[image: observation 2, 3 task1 threads and 7 task 2 threads]

Again, i expect that there should be a symmetric number of threads for both task1 and task 2, and I also expect that the abslute values of i and j should grow more proportionately than they are. Any insight on how to mitigate this discrepancy or avoid this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I copied the posted code into a `test.py` file and ran it from the command line (`python3 ./test.py`), and after commenting-out the `from IPython.display import clear_output` and `clear_output(wait=True)` lines, it runs as you would expect (only two threads shown, printed values are roughly the negative equivalents of each other, and they increase every 5 seconds).  Perhaps it is something about the Jupyter environment that is making act funny for you.

Comment: Just tried this, it does seem to be an issue with jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in Jupyter and didn't have your problem.

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 139735228168000)>
<Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 139735083251456)>
<Heartbeat(Thread-2, started daemon 139735074858752)>
<HistorySavingThread(IPythonHistorySavingThread, started 139735049680640)>
<Thread(task2, started 139734638634752)>
<Thread(task1, started 139734680598272)>
<Thread(task2, started 139735041287936)>
<Thread(task1, started 139734076618496)>
<Thread(task1, started 139735032895232)>
<Thread(task2, started 139734672205568)>
<Thread(task1, started 139734655420160)>
<Thread(task2, started 139734630242048)>
272
-272
```

But as you already saw with your own code, there are multiple instances of each task running. So after a task 'has started itself anew' it takes some time before it kills itself.

A solution to your Jupyter problem could be to give the main function the control of restarting a killed tasked. This ensures that always only 1 thread of each task is running.

```
import threading
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time

i = 0
j = 0

main_stop = False


def task1():
    global i
    i += 1
    time.sleep(4)


def task2():
    global j
    j -= 1
    time.sleep(4)


def main():
    global i
    global j
    t1 = threading.Thread(name="task1", target=task1)
    t2 = threading.Thread(name="task2", target=task2)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    while not main_stop:
        if not t1.is_alive():
            del t1
            t1 = threading.Thread(name="task1", target=task1)
            t1.start()
        if not t2.is_alive():
            del t2
            t2 = threading.Thread(name="task2", target=task2)
            t2.start()

    # wait for tasks to complete
    while t1.is_alive():
        time.sleep(0.1)
    while t2.is_alive():
        time.sleep(0.1)


tmain = threading.Thread(name="main", target=main)
tmain.start()

run_time = 30   # seconds
end_time = time.time() + run_time
while time.time() < end_time:

    clear_output(wait=True)
    for thread in threading.enumerate():
        print(thread)
    print(i)
    print(j)
    time.sleep(0.1)

main_stop = True
# wait for main to complete
while tmain.is_alive():
    time.sleep(0.1)

print('program completed')
```